# Cannot restore SharePoint farm, from Full/Differential Backup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, restore

i have an weird problem with retoration SharePoint farm

i cannot restore the test environnement from Full & Differential farm Backup (in the central administration) , from 10 days

despite it was possible before

[image]

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the backups which are not able to restore are finished and there are not errors or warnings for them. You can check "View backup and restore history" to check that.

In my testing, if a backup is not finished because of some things, we are unable to restore using the backup file, like:
[image]

Comment: Thank's ALL

finaly , finally the problem was the trigger delay , it was fixed for tw0 (2) Howrs and the Backup operation has taken more than that.

Best Regards